# Touchpad does not work anymore. How to reenable?

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad

I don't know what I did and if it was my fault. But for  two days my touchpad does not work anymore.

Facts:

- I have no xorg.conf.
- Ubuntu system settings (gnome-control-center) don't show the mousepad.
- gconf-tool says touchpad is enabled.
- xinput list says touchpad is enabled. (SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad)
- In Windows it works so no hardware problem here.
- I use awesome, but in unity it does not work too.
- New: Tap for a mouseclick click works!!

I don't know if I had an xorg.conf before.  Awesome WM worked with the pad before. But I read something about lightdm-session or gnome-session-manager disabling the pad. These are two tools I played around with because awesome starts none of them. Any approaches to solve this?

**My pad works again. And I don't know why!!!!**

Comment: Have you tried this in "reverse"? http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20235/18110

Comment: Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad': Device Enabled (133):   1 ... well, thanks anyway

Comment: Could it be settings like very low sensitivity, bogus region definition or palmdetect settings, What's the output of `synclient`?

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same issue here (but tapping doesn't work, but touchpad buttons works fine).

my synclient says:

```
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
```

and

```
xinput list-props "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
Device 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (135):   1
```

I also use awesome, but on unity it doesn't work as well.

But this helped in my case:

```
$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-multitouch
$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
$ sudo reboot
```

Comment: I think that the package name is `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`